# AngularJS - How to properly get response header value from within interceptor service

Tags: angularjs, http

I am trying to read a response header value from AngularJS in an interceptor service I defined in my app.

I am getting an undefined returned in the alert dialog and can not determine how to get the response header value "appVersion".

JSON of response.headers()

```
{
    "etag": "W/\"ca3-159d3673a17\"",
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    "content-length": "3235",
    "accept-ranges": "bytes",
    "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",
    "last-modified": "Wed, 25 Jan 2017 02:14:34 GMT",
    "date": "Mon, 30 Jan 2017 19:53:11 GMT"
}
{
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "expires": "-1"

}
```

The interceptor service looks like

```
app.service("versionCheckInterceptorService", ['$rootScope','$location', 'localStorageService', function ($rootScope,$location,localStorageService) {

    return {
        response: function (response) {
          var swAuthToken = localStorageService.get('swAuthToken');
          var appVersion = swAuthToken.appVersion;
          alert(response.headers().appVersion);  <---------Returns undefined
          return response;
         }
    }


}]);
```

Response Headers (from browser inspector)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 9461
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
appVersion: 1.1.1     <---------I need to get appVersion in AngularJS
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Mon, 30 Jan 2017 19:10:44 GMT
```

**Is my method of getting response header correct and what do I need to do to properly get appVersion in my app?**

Comment: Evaluation of response.headers() produces JSON but no appVersion as a key value pair.

Comment: can you post that json from response.headers()

Comment: Please see edits.

Comment: why there are two jsons?

Comment: Try setting `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` to appVersion in response headers from your server.

Comment: @Sangharsh, does this require modification to an API?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be added as a header in API response